# Performance difference when assigning in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, performance

I would like to know if there is any difference in performance between these:
- create an object with the value of an existing object, then assign itself = a modified version of it
AND
- create and object with the value = the modified value of an existing object

Code sample in Objective-C:

```
UIImage* img= img2;
img = [img apply:filter];
```

***VS***

```
UIImage* img=[img2 apply:filter];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
UIImage* img= img2;
```

does not "create a new object", it simply makes "img" refer to the same object as "img2".

In either case, all you're doing is assigning a pointer, so there's no significant performance difference.

Comment: I must have forgotten the basic concept of pointers & memory allocation, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1):

If the `apply` method always returns a new image, then no, there is not the slightest difference between those two things. The main difference is that in the first one, the first line is wasted: you assign img2 to img but then you throw away that assignment, replacing img's value a different image (the result of `apply`). But even that waste makes no performance difference, because object assignment is pointer assignment, which is trivial (no data copying takes place or anything like that).

Answer (score 0):

At this level, you're dealing with something the compiler will optimize away anyway.  There may be an additional assignment that occurs in the first that doesn't happen in the second (that would have a negligible impact on performance because you're simply dealing with pointers), but I imagine any compiler worth its salt would turn these two statements into the same assembly.